# Login loop in 15.04 after upgrading to kernel 3.19.0-26-generic

Tags: upgrade, kernel, login, 15.04

Today I've updated the kernel from 3.19.0.25-generic to 3.19.0.26-generic, and now I get a login loop. After I input the (correct) password, the login screen keeps reappearing over and over.
If in the Grub I choose previous version of the kernel (3.19.0.25-generic) I can login normally.

I don't even know where to start looking and which logs would be helpful. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Did you install any video drivers downloading them from vendor site?

Comment: I have fglrx, fglrx-amdcccle and fglrx-core installed but I installed them from ubuntu repositories. I tried to remove those and the problem went away, but I was left without proper graphics driver. Now I reverted back to previous kernel, but kept the fglrx* installed. I also found an issue simmilar to mine: https://lists.launchpad.net/kernel-packages/msg129140.html
I'll keep it this way until better solution is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in `fglrx-updates_2:15.200-0ubuntu4.2` for Ubuntu 15.04 and `fglrx-updates_2:15.200-0ubuntu0.5` for 14.04.

It has been released already. Just wait till this version appears in updates.

The package can be downloaded not from [HERE](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-updates/2:15.200-0ubuntu4.2)

This is the [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1479913).

Comment: I'll wait until this version is available to me and I'll report back afterwards.

Comment: Confirmed. I'm now running kernel 3.19.0.26-generic and fglrx 2:15.200-0ubuntu4.2 with no problem.